# limit of sequence with factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, factorial

How do you show that:
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}{n!}=0$
using the squeeze theorem (I'd like to avoid using Stirling's formula, too). I tried rearranging it a bit into $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{n}\right)^{n}}{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}n!}$ , but i can't really figure out what to do next. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired limit is equivalent to

$$lim_{n->\infty} {\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}}$$

Since

$$n^n < 2n*(2n-1)*...*(n+1)$$

we have the majorant

$$\frac{1}{n!}$$

which clearly tends to 0, if n tends to infinity.

Comment: Sorry if I may be asking a basic question. While I do understand the inequality in the second line of your answer, can you please explain the equivalence part and what you mean by majorant. Many thanks

Comment: The sequence $\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}$ is smaller than the sequence $\frac{1}{n!}$ (both sequences only have positive elements). So, $\frac{1}{n!}$ is called a majorant. If the majorant (the larger sequence) tends to 0, the given one also must tend to 0 (squeeze-theorem) in the case of positive sequences.

Comment: Can't believe how easy that was. Thanks again.